# qrcode scaner implementation on wp page

Tags: javascript, php, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a QR code scanner on my Wordpress page or in a popup, so when users visit the page/popup link, he/she will be able to scan a QR code. The QR code is basically a woocommerce product url, so I want the QR code scanner to only proceed if the QR code is generated from my site. Other QR codes, that are not generated from my site, can be read but just show information like URL or code without redirecting to the URL.

The scenario is: I create a woocommerce product with the QR code, then I place QR code on menu/table in restoran. Users will visit my site and open the QR code scanner page, then scan the QR code, and they will be automatically redirected to the woocommerce product. If the QR code is not generated from my website it will not redirect but just show information inside the QR code.

I found this WP plugin but it's totally not working: https://github.com/eManagerNYC/QR-Code-Scanner

I found another method using an html5 QRcode scanner from this: https://github.com/dwa012/html5-qrcode

But it's about 4 years old, and this JavaScript QR Code scanner for HTML5 supporting browsers: https://github.com/jbialobr/JsQRScanner but I don't know how to install or implement it.

Place all the files from the `js` directory on your server.

Add the js script into your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jsqrscanner.nocache.js"></script>
```

Create a scanner control and append it to the DOM.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function onQRCodeScanned(scannedText)
    {
        var scannedTextMemo = document.getElementById("scannedTextMemo");
        if(scannedTextMemo)
        {
            scannedTextMemo.value = scannedText;
        }
    }

    //this function will be called when JsQRScanner is ready to use
    function JsQRScannerReady()
    {
        //create a new scanner passing to it a callback function that will be invoked when
        //the scanner succesfully scan a QR code
        var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(onQRCodeScanned);
        //reduce the size of analyzed images to increase performance on mobile devices
        jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
        var scannerParentElement = document.getElementById("scanner");
        if(scannerParentElement)
        {
            //append the jbScanner to an existing DOM element
            jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
        }        
    }
  </script>
```

Providing a video stream in a custom way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onQRCodeScanned(scannedText)
    {
        var scannedTextMemo = document.getElementById("scannedTextMemo");
        if(scannedTextMemo)
        {
            scannedTextMemo.value = scannedText;
        }
    }

    //funtion returning a promise with a video stream
    function provideVideoQQ()
    {
        return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        .then(function(devices) {
            var exCameras = [];
            devices.forEach(function(device) {
            if (device.kind === 'videoinput') {
              exCameras.push(device.deviceId)
            }
         });

            return Promise.resolve(exCameras);
        }).then(function(ids){
            if(ids.length === 0)
            {
              return Promise.reject('Could not find a webcam');
            }

            return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: {
                  'optional': [{
                    'sourceId': ids.length === 1 ? ids[0] : ids[1]//this way QQ browser opens the rear camera
                    }]
                }
            });        
        });                
    }  

    //this function will be called when JsQRScanner is ready to use
    function JsQRScannerReady()
    {
        //create a new scanner passing to it a callback function that will be invoked when
        //the scanner succesfully scan a QR code
        var jbScanner = new JsQRScanner(onQRCodeScanned, provideVideoQQ);
        //reduce the size of analyzed images to increase performance on mobile devices
        jbScanner.setSnapImageMaxSize(300);
        var scannerParentElement = document.getElementById("scanner");
        if(scannerParentElement)
        {
            //append the jbScanner to an existing DOM element
            jbScanner.appendTo(scannerParentElement);
        }        
    }
  </script>
```

If anyone can help me with how to implement this code on wordpress page it will be really appreciated.

Comment: have you get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The credit of this work goes to Chris Schmich

https://github.com/schmich
The code was designed to alert the content of the QR code scanner I have modified it slightly to display the QR code into the web browser instead of the local alert message.

This methods works it will open the URL Link that is encoded in your QRCode in a new window tab, make sure you download the libraries from

https://github.com/schmich/instascan/releases

It works 100% provided you should download the libraries from the above link and add in the src of script tag inside the head tag.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
            <script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                #preview{
                   width:500px;
                   height: 500px;
                   margin:0px auto;
                }
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h1 style="color:blue">Scan your QRCode</h1>
                    <video id="preview"></video>
        
            
            <script src="https://rawgit.com/schmich/instascan-builds/master/instascan.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({ video: document.getElementById('preview'), scanPeriod: 5, mirror: false });
                scanner.addListener('scan',function(content){
        
                    window.location.href=content;
                });
                Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras){
                    if(cameras.length>0){
                        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                        $('[name="options"]').on('change',function(){
                            if($(this).val()==1){
                                if(cameras[0]!=""){
                                    scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                                }else{
                                    alert('No Front camera found!');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        console.error('No cameras found.');
                        alert('No cameras found.');
                    }
                }).catch(function(e){
                    console.error(e);
                });
            </script>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle mb-5" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-primary active">
                <input type="radio" name="options" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked> Front Camera
              </label>
            </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

To generate qrcode you can use the following code snippet,

$qrcode = base_url().'MPDF/mpdf/index'; //your URL Link here goes inhere after '=' assign it to $qrcode

```
        $this->load->library('ciqrcode');

        $params['data'] = $qrcode;
        $params['level'] = 'H';
        $params['size'] = 10;
        $params['savename'] = FCPATH.'public/uploads/tes.png';
        $this->ciqrcode->generate($params);
```

Comment: So this code will ask permission for camera to activate, then you take a photo of qr through the browser and then the result (say a website) will load ?

Comment: $params['savename'] = FCPATH.'public/uploads/tes.png';  saves the qrcode as tes.png,  this image of qrcode should be presented in front of your camera, preferably you have it in your cellphone and just wave it in front of your camera using your cellphone, it should take you to $param['data'] , here in my case is a pdf file in mpdf/index, i will print the pdf after shwoing the qrcode in front of my camera,